# Disabling the rest of the radiobuttons after 3 selections on Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a poll with 7 radiobuttons as selections. How would I make it so that after they select 
3 radiobuttons, the rest of the radiobutton selections are unabled to be selected and clicked? Or is there an easier way to this approach? Thanks.

```
// Event handler for radio buttons
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();





    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.RadioButton1:
        if (checked) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: Hindi",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton2:
        if (checked)
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: English",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton3:
        if (checked) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: English",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            numThree++;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton4:
        if (checked) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: English",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton6:
        if (checked) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: English",

        }
        break;
    case R.id.RadioButton7:
        if (checked) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: English",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use check boxes as radio buttons usually mean a single option selection.

You can have a counter that is 0 initially and gets increased by one when a check box is checked and decreased by one when unchecked. Once the counter is 3 you disable all unchecked choices.

Answer (score 0):

A radio button is best for when only one option can be selected at a time. I'd recommend using checkboxes instead, like:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

int count = 0;
int maxSelected = 3;

// .....

case R.id.RadioButton1:
    if (checked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: Hindi",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               //LIKE THIS 
                count += 1;
                if(count>maxSelected) {
                     disableCheckboxes(); //this would move through and disable any checkbox that wasn't selected
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easiest way of solving your problem. If you really want to use radio button you have to use radio button without radio button group. Click on radio button should be done manually. By checking click on radio button you have to increase or decrease number of total on radio button. 
I am showing you only for two button.you must do the rest.

```
RadioButton radio1;
RadioButton radio2;
static int totalselectedRadioButton=0;

radio1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean isChecked = radio1.isSelected();
// on radio button
            if (!isChecked) {
                radio1.setSelected(true);
                radio1.setChecked(true);
                totalselectedRadioButton ++;
//disable other button when reached expected total Selected radio button
                if(totalselectedRadioButton>0) {
                    radio2.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
            else {
                radio1.setSelected(false);
                radio1.setChecked(false);
                totalselectedRadioButton --;
                if(totalselectedRadioButton<1) {
                    radio2.setClickable(true);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```